# check if data exists in database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm making an application that has an user database and I was wondering what's the best way to check if user exists in database while filling and registration form.
I have a database called users. it consists of 3 columns: id, userName and Password.

Here's my code for the inserting into database :

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HRC0;Initial Catalog=users;Integrated Security=True");
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("insert into users (userName, password) values('" + korisnik.Text + "','" + pass.Text + "');", con);
 int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
 MessageBox.Show(o + " Ubačeni ste u bazu korisnika!");
 con.Close();
 this.Hide();
 new Form1().Show();
```

Korisnik is the name of the textbox in which you write your username and pass is the textbox where you write your password.
And the messagebox is saying that you're added to the userbase.

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Sql Server?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2 and the databases were created in his management studio.

Answer (score 1):

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using(var sc = new SqlCommand("if NOT exists (select * from users where UserName = @username) insert into users (userName, password) values(@userName, @password)",con))
{
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", korisnik.Text);
    sc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pass.Text);
    con.Open();
    int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this query returns true if user exists and false if not (assume usernames are unique)

```
select 
  cast ((case 
           when exists (select null from Users where UserName = @username) 
           then 1 else 0 end) as bit)
```

To call it use this code

```
cmd.Text = "..text above.."
cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.nvarchar).Value = korisnik.Text;
var result = (bool)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Never concatenate your query the way you showed in question, it leads to sql injections.